# How to connect to oracle and retrive data

Tags: playframework-2.3

I am new to Java and Playframework as well. I have play running. But am unable to retrieve data from oracle. I added the /lib folder and added the ojdbc6.jar and play deployed successfully. I know play is connected to my DB as when I had the incorrect config it complained. The config is below in the application.conf

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:SOMESID"  
db.default.user=someuser
db.default.password=somepassword
```

All the above seems ok. Now in the application.java I am trying to fetch data from DB. I do not want to use Hibernate or any ORM layers. The **application.java** is below. Added the method **getMetaData** to talk to Oracle but does not work. Perhaps I have not written the method properly or not imported the relevant libraries. A working .java file would be very helpful. If I can manage to retrieve data form oracle great otherwise hope I don't have to go the spring framework route. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
package controllers;

import play.*;

import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import play.db.*;

public class Application extends Controller {
public static Result index() {
   //return ok(index.render("Hello Worldxxx"));
    //me: the below is the default return
    return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
}

public static Result tasks() {
return TODO;
}

public static Result newTask() {
return TODO;
}

public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {
return TODO;
}

public static Result getMetaData() {            
Connection connection = DB.getConnection();
ResultSet resultSet = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM     sometable").executeQuery();
             metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
             connection.close();
             return ok(metaData.toString());
}
}
```